# Winforms - Invoking a method in another thread

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

What is the best practice to invoke a method in a different thread from a winform button so the ui doesn't freeze or creates a delay?

Comment: Have a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fit-it%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v%3Dvs.95).aspx&ei=IVb1ULX0IoiZtQb-_YGIDQ&usg=AFQjCNFRVGcrEN3-rSleLQLwxJfbUgg1dA&bvm=bv.41018144,d.Yms), it has been created specifically for this purpose...

Comment: @Soner: Thanks, but I disagree. There are thread solutions fitted specific to WinForms ui controls. I think your title makes it too generic. (such as BeginInvoke). Re-edited.

Answer (score 6):

In a first step start with

- [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

If this doesn't meet your requirements or you need more advanced stuff you should take a look into one of these:

- [`Task Parallel Library`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)
- [`ReactiveExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577611.aspx)
- [`async / await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
    DoSomething();
});
```

Comment: That sounds like the opposite way from a background thread to the UI thread.

Comment: @UweKeim: Not sure what you mean. This code can be used to call a method from a thread that's not the UI thread. Seems to me that it's what the OP asked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that he means the opposite of what you mean :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Control.Invoke` or `BeginInvoke`, see in-depth reference [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/pages/126345.aspx).

Comment: That's the opposite way, what you are describing.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this

```
 Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
 {         
      //DO SOMETHING         
 }
```