# Why do I get this error when using a thread?

Tags: c#, post, listbox

So, I got my program working, but it becomes unresponsive when I run it, so I decided to run it in a thread. Now, I kept everything the same, but instead of using a button to run the code directly, I'm using a button to run a thread that contains the code. What the program is doing is creating a request to a webpage, getting the cookie from the webpage, then run through a list of numbers, using those numbers to create different POST requests using the cookie to log in.

Working:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cookie = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie;
        List<string> removals = new List<string>();
        foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
        { 
          //do stuff
        }
    }
```

Not working:

```
thread th;
    public void thread()
        {
            string cookie = webBrowser1.Document.Cookie;
            List<string> removals = new List<string>();
            foreach (string s in listBox1.Items)
            {
             //do stuff
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            th = new Thread(thread);
            th.Start();
        }
```

Error: http://prntscr.com/1mabtb

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're presumably using WinForms in which case you should invoke actions on the webBrowser1 control such that your interactions are performed on the UI thread instead of your newly created thread. See the series of answers here:

[Winforms - Invoking a method in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338504/winforms-invoking-a-method-in-another-thread)